# Cut output of shell with starts and finishes specific character

Tags: shell, cut

I have a html/text file which has downloadable URL of video but I need to cut the file as link.

For example, it starts with `url240=` or `url360=` or 480 etc. and there is URL `LinkOfUrl` and finishes with `&amp;jpg...`

I want to get output like `url240=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA` or **this is my point** -->> `https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA`

**How can I  do?**

My aim is that grabbing video link and downloading it from terminal not using browser or not using manually entires. I am planning to write a shell script to do it automatically so I need to assign link as variable after that I will use `axel $variable` .  (I used wget to get html/text files if anyone wondered it how I  get.)

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU9v801buWQdnRadU9KMm5WbUE/view) is my original html/text file

There is small text of file which I have :

`</param> <param name="flashvars" value="uid=313752528&amp;vid=171193750&amp;oid=313752528&amp;host=https://cs542402.vk.me/&amp;vtag=68ec547387&amp;ltag=l_f4d9714c&amp;vkid=171193750&amp;md_title=Hi.Ki3+ep08&amp;md_author=Kadem+%26%23199%3Belik&amp;author_href=/id313752528&amp;hd=3&amp;no_flv=1&amp;hd_def=0&amp;dbg_on=0&amp;t=0&amp;duration=1399&amp;thumb=https://pp.vk.me/c621922/v621922528/26d5d/buRyDSImp1Y.jpg&amp;hash=17cc43bba064a6bd4c887b2b336e28a1&amp;hash2=8a5ce8fb95dac3b7&amp;angle=0&amp;img_angle=0&amp;repeat=0&amp;show_ads=0&amp;show_ads_postroll=0&amp;legal_owner=0&amp;eid1=0&amp;slot=0&amp;g=0&amp;a=0&amp;puid34=0&amp;water_mark=&amp;can_rotate=1&amp;no_adfox=1&amp;ads_preview=0&amp;puid4=0&amp;url240=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA&amp;url360=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.360.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA&amp;url480=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.480.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA&amp;url720=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.720.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA&amp;jpg=https://pp.vk.me/c621922/v621922528/26d5c/Hqe6Th45LmA.jpg&amp;timeline_thumbs=1&amp;timeline_thumbs_jpg=https://pp.vk.me/c623120/v623120528/403ab/W0o1WeSlf5o.jpg,https://pp.vk.me/c622717/v622717528/3bcdc/enzNOAL2PJw.jpg,https://pp.vk.me/c625626/v625626528/3edb9/y44h0j9UBT4.jpg&amp;timeline_thumbs_per_row=10&amp;timeline_thumbs_per_image=100&amp;timeline_thumbs_total=279&amp;timeline_thumb_width=133&amp;timeline_thumb_height=75&amp;ip_subm=1&amp;proxy=psv4&amp;https=1&amp;video_ext=1&amp;is_yandex=0&apm;&amp;is_vk=1&amp;is_ext=1&amp;referrer=&amp;lang_add=Add+to+My+Videos&amp;lang_added=Video+added+to+My+Videos&amp;lang_share=Share&amp;lang_like=Like&amp;lang_volume_on=Unmute&amp;lang_volume_off=Mute&amp;lang_volume=Volume&amp;lang_hdsd=Change+Video+Quality&amp;lang_open_popup=Expand&amp;lang_fullscreen=Full+Screen&amp;lang_window=Minimize&amp;lang_rotate=Rotate&amp;lang_ads_link=Advertiser%27s+Site&amp;lang_ads=Ads&amp;lang_ads_skip=Skip+ad&amp;lang_next=Next+video&amp;lang_replay=Replay&amp;lang_next_cancel=Cancel&amp;lang_ads_skip_time=Skip+ads+in+%7Btime%7D&amp;lang_report_problem=Report+a+problem..&amp;video_play_hd=Watch+in+HD&amp;video_stop_loading=Stop+Download&amp;video_player_version=VK+Video+Player&amp;goto_orig_video=Go+to+Video&amp;video_get_video_code=Copy+video+code&amp;video_load_error=The+video+has+not+uploaded+yet+or+the+server+is+not+available&amp;video_get_current_url=Copy+frame+link"></param> <param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param> <embed id="flash_video_obj" align="top" src="/swf/video.swf?94" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="100%" wmode="opaque" flashvars=uid=313752528&amp;vid=171193750&amp;oid=313752528&amp;host=https://cs542402.vk.me/&amp;vtag=68ec547387&amp;ltag=l_f4d9714c&amp;vkid=171193750&amp;md_title=Hi.Ki3+ep08&amp;md_author=Kadem+%26%23199%3Belik&amp;author_href=/id313752528&amp;hd=3&amp;no_flv=1&amp;hd_def=0&amp;dbg_on=0&amp;t=0&amp;duration=1399&amp;thumb=https://pp.vk.me/c621922/v621922528/26d5d/buRyDSImp1Y.jpg&amp;hash=17cc43bba064a6bd4c887b2b336e28a1&amp;hash2=8a5ce8fb95dac3b7&amp;angle=0&amp;img_angle=0&amp;repeat=0&amp;show_ads=0&amp;show_ads_postroll=0&amp;legal_owner=0&amp;eid1=0&amp;slot=0&amp;g=0&amp;a=0&amp;puid34=0&amp;water_mark=&amp;can_rotate=1&amp;no_adfox=1&amp;ads_preview=0&amp;puid4=0&amp;url240=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA&amp;url360=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.360.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA&amp;url480=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.480.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA&amp;url720=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.720.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA&amp;jpg=https://pp.vk.me/c621922/v621922528/26d5c/Hqe6Th45LmA.jpg&amp;timeline_thumbs=1&amp;timeline_thumbs_jpg=https://pp.vk.me/c623120/v623120528/403ab/W0o1WeSlf5o.jpg,https://pp.vk.me/c622717/v622717528/3bcdc/enzNOAL2PJw.jpg,https://pp.vk.me/c625626/v625626528/3edb9/y44h0j9UBT4.jpg&amp;timeline_thumbs_per_row=10&amp;timeline_thumbs_per_image=100&amp;timeline_thumbs_total=279&amp;timeline_thumb_width=133&amp;timeline_thumb_height=75&amp;ip_subm=1&amp;proxy=psv4&amp;https=1&amp;video_ext=1&amp;is_yandex=0&apm;&amp;is_vk=1&amp;is_ext=1&amp;referrer=&amp;lang_add=Add+to+My+Videos&amp;lang_added=Video+added+to+My+Videos&amp;lang_share=Share&amp;lang_like=Like&amp;lang_volume_on=Unmute&amp;lang_volume_off=Mute&amp;lang_volume=Volume&amp;lang_hdsd=Change+Video+Quality&amp;lang_open_popup=Expand&amp;lang_fullscreen=Full+Screen&amp;lang_window=Minimize&amp;lang_rotate=Rotate&amp;lang_ads_link=Advertiser%27s+Site&amp;lang_ads=Ads&amp;lang_ads_skip=Skip+ad&amp;lang_next=Next+video&amp;lang_replay=Replay&amp;lang_next_cancel=Cancel&amp;lang_ads_skip_time=Skip+ads+in+%7Btime%7D&amp;lang_report_problem=Report+a+problem..&amp;video_play_hd=Watch+in+HD&amp;video_stop_loading=Stop+Download&amp;video_player_version=VK+Video+Player&amp;goto_orig_video=Go+to+Video&amp;video_get_video_code=Copy+video+code&amp;video_load_error=The+video+has+not+uploaded+yet+or+the+server+is+not+available&amp;video_get_current_url=Copy+frame+link></embed> </object>`

Comment: I can't add small text of my file. So if you can't open my drive document, please notify me

Comment: No, [edit] your question so that it contains a valid sample input together with a desired output - and your attempts. You may want to read [ask]

Comment: It gives me error when I add small text. Like that `the question doesn't have requirement our policy`

Comment: This is a sample input. So given this, what would be the desired output? And, important: what did you try so far?

Comment: I try to get an output like `https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA` because I will use the **output ** as variable.

Comment: Again: [edit] your question with this info. And read [ask].

Comment: It has already written in question. It starts with `I want to get output like... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you some ideas...

```
sed 's/&amp;/\n/g' | grep url240 | cut -d= -f2
```

separate parameters joined by "&", grep the required line, get the right handside of the = sign.

If you have = sign in the contents, just cut based on the variable name length.  For example

```
var="url240"; sed 's/&amp;/\n/g' | grep $var | cut -c $((${#var}+2))-
```

Comment: Thanks your replay but I need more powerful command because of cut command. Because in video link has `=` sign after `extra` word so it can not use as a variable. This is my output `https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra
https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra
 {"uid":"313752528","vid":171193750,"oid":313752528,"host":"https:\/\/cs542402.vk.me\/","vtag":"68ec547387","ltag":"l_f4d9714c","vkid":171193750,"md_title":"Hi.Ki3+ep08","md_author".....(blablabla)...\/cs542402.vk.me\/6\/u313752528\/videos\/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra`

Comment: thanks for your help. I want to vote UP but I am new at stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much karakfa because your ideas.!!
I solved my issue with this command :

```
sed 's/&amp;/\n/g' MyFile  | grep url240 | sed -n '1p'
```

This first sed command replaced `&amp;` with space charecter so after that with grep I get 3 lines (last line is so long). After that with `sed` I cut the first line from output and now it works well. But my output looks like that

```
url240=https://cs542402.vk.me/6/u313752528/videos/68ec547387.240.mp4?extra=JVSeMzU2-msXVuseackTFCgnVNEPOnboxMdXN3ZGH1l91djR7bk9DzaxyKFGJ2SXg39BcZxJM6tBip0ui3dDEkULDSbkuzpaOA
```

So, I added `tail -c +8` and my final command looks like this

```
sed 's/&amp;/\n/g' MyFile  | grep url240 | sed -n '1p' | tail -c +8
```